# Using NSSortDescriptor to sort objects in NSMutableArray iOS?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I have an NSMutableArray of Objects. I need to sort them based on createdDate and name.
Below is the scenario which i am facing:
File Names are like this:
Image.pdf, Image 1.pdf, Image 2.pdf, Image 3.pdf, Image 4.pdf, Image 5.pdf...

Now these files can have same createdDate so when createdDate is same then it should be sorted by name in descending order. So if above files have same created date then after sorting it should be displayed as:
Image 5.pdf, Image 4.pdf, Image 3.pdf, Image 2.pdf, Image 1.pdf, Image.pdf but when i use below code Image.pdf is jumbled or displayed like this:
   Image.pdf, Image 5.pdf, Image 4.pdf, Image 3.pdf, Image 3.pdf, Image 1.pdf

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdDate" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil];
    return sortDescriptors;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong logic I guess, first you have to check all the file have same date or not, if they have same date then only sort by name else sort by date.

Comment: Can you add more insight on that how can that be achieved.

Comment: First you need to rephrase your question, and make it more readable and make understand so I can suggest something.

Comment: Let say i get 3 files of date 02-Apr-2015 with names : Image.pdf, Image 1.pdf, Image 3.pdf                                                                              Sort Order: Image 3.pdf, Image 1.pdf, Image.pdf                               Now i get 4 more files of date 03-ape-2015 with names: Image 7.pdf, Image 8.pdf, Image 9.pdf, Image 2.pdf                                                Sorting Order: Image 9.pdf, Image 8.pdf, Image 7.pdf, Image2.pdf, Image 3.pdf, Image 1.pdf, Image.pdf

Answer (score 0):

String representation of integers give undefined behavior, so when you are comparing `@"Image 1.pdf" < @"Image 2.pdf"`, will have an undefined behavior.

What you can do is try to first get that number which is appended to "Image" and then try to sort it.